# How to read file into dictionary in python

Tags: python

I have a text file in the format of the following:

```
hsa04012 [[['7039', '1956', '1398', '25'], ['7039', '1956', '1399', '25']], [['1839', '1956', '1398', '25'], ['1839', '1956', '1399', '25']], [['1399', '25']], [['1398', '25']], [['727738', '1956', '1398', '25'], ['727738', '1956', '1399', '25']], [['1956', '1398', '25'], ['1956', '1399', '25']], [['1950', '1956', '1398', '25'], ['1950', '1956', '1399', '25']], [['374', '1956', '1398', '25'], ['374', '1956', '1399', '25']], [['2069', '1956', '1398', '25'], ['2069', '1956', '1399', '25']], [['685', '1956', '1398', '25'], ['685', '1956', '1399', '25']]]
hsa02331...
```

How can I read the file into a dictionary with the key as the text containing hsa... and the value as the numbers within the brackets [as a list].

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use `str.split` and [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).  That seems easiest...

```
with open(datafile) as f:
    d = {}
    for line in f:
        key,value = line.split(None,1)
        d[key] = ast.literal_eval(value)
```

Although, you might be able to play some games with `json` to get the lists as well. The lists look to be quite valid JSON arrays, as they are called.